# grep lines starting with "1" in Ubuntu

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I try to search for lines that start with "1" using

```
ls -1 | grep ^1*
```

but it returns lines that do not start with 1. What I am missing here?

Comment: Just another note: If you want to use grep to limit `ls` output, you will run into problems if filenames contain some weird characters, such as newlines... Many other commands (somehow not `ls`, at least not the version that I have to check) have a option to give null separated output, which you can then safely process with `grep -z`

Comment: Thanks, @GertvandenBerg! What problems can some weird characters such as newlines cause to grep? What commands give null separated output?

Comment: find with -print0, most other GNU tool have a -0 or -z option. (sort, xargs, etc as well). If the filenames contain newlines, the it would be impossible to know if two lines are a filename containing a newline or two seperate filenames.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't mean what you think it does. It matches all lines starting (^) with one (1) repeated zero or more (*) times. All strings match that regular expression. `grep '^1'` does what you want.

Comment: or likewise this works:  `grep "^$some_var"`

Answer (score 55):

Did you try the following?

```
 ls -1 | grep "^1"
```

That is, remove the `*`, which basically tells `grep`, find zero or more occurances of the `^1` expression. In other words: match the lines that start with a 1, or not.

Answer (score 13):

Although this doesn't answer your question, this is a better solution to what appears to be your goal:

```
ls -ld 1*
```

You can use a shell glob to list all files that start with `1`. Note that `*` has a different meaning in shell globbing than regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks! +1. How does * have different meaning in shell globbing and in regular expressions?

Comment: In a [shell glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) `*` is a wildcard meaning "0 or more of *any* character". The regex meaning is explained in otokan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

^1.* matches the whole line,
or just as said above, ^1 got the string contained in the line.

different styles of regex uses different symbols representing chars, some options specify which style you want.
and different options specify whether you want to match the whole line, or just part of it, or the whole input as one string.