# grep for a text in a line. But if it has a comment only at its beginning then exclude it from the grep

Tags: grep

I'm trying to grep for a instance "test" in /etc/oratab. But wanted to display only the line that doesn't begin with a comment. Below are the lines from /etc/oratab file:

```
#test:/u01/appl/oracle/test/db/tech_st/12.1.0.2:N
test:/b001/app/oracle/testrac/db/tech_st/12.1.0.2:N         # line added by Agent
```

This is how I'm trying to get the details I'm interested in (placed the below in a shell script:

```
DB_NAME=test
env_var=`cat /etc/oratab |grep $DB_NAME |grep -v '#' |cut -d":" -f 2`
echo $env_var
```

The problem here is, as the 2nd line also has a comment at its end, it is also being ignored.

Please help.

Regards,
RA

Comment: What?  This is not the year’s best question, but [that one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59893/80216) is of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler solution than re-writing it to use awk would be to add a simple ^ to indicate the start of a line:

```
env_var=`cat /etc/oratab |grep $DB_NAME |grep -v '^#' |cut -d":" -f 2`
```

The `grep -v '^#'` removes all lines starting with a # and is often useful.

Comment: ITYM `grep "^$DB_NAME:"`. That could still give false positives for values of DB_NAME like "test.2" which would match on "test12" for instance.

Comment: No, he wants to filter out the commented lines which my solution does.

Comment: @Mikael. Yes, your solution worked. But if you notice, the second line also has a comment, then how come it was captured. Please excuse me if I'm being naive. Thank you.

Comment: @user206245 `^#` matches only a `#` at the beginning of the line, that's the small difference to your attempt

Comment: But this will find ``unwanted line:blah:blah #test`` (which the OP probably does not want it to find).

Comment: I don't follow. In his example he only wanted to remove fully commented lines not lines with comments in them.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` would be a better choice here:

```
DB_NAME=test; export DB_NAME
file=$(awk -F: '$1 == ENVIRON["DB_NAME"] {print $2; exit}' < /etc/oratab)

printf '%s\n' "$file"
```

On Solaris, make sure to do:

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH
```

(and use `#! /usr/xpg4/bin/sh -` if on Solaris 10 and older) to have standard utilities. Or use `command -p awk`. Otherwise, you may get an antiquated `awk` from the 70s.

Comment: @ Stephane. It worked. But did not understand the logic. Could you please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, you can combine both `grep`s and the `cut` in one pass:

```
sed "/^$DB_NAME:/! d;s///;s/:.*//" /etc/oratab
```

With

- `/^$DB_NAME:/` selects all lines starting with `$DB_NAME` followed by `:`; the `!` inverts the match, so the following `d` deleted all lines that don't match this pattern
- `s///` removes the last match, in this case the `test:`
- `s/:.*//` removes the `:` and everything following

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work for the example
(file is CSV* (colon-separated values),
searched-for string will be the first field,
desired output is the second field),
but none of these constraints / conditions
is actually *stated* in the question. 
And, while the question asks for a command
that excludes lines that *begin* with a comment,
that’s probably not what the OP really wants. 
(What about a line like `unwanted line:blah:blah #test`,
which contains `test` *in a comment*?) 
The answer that the OP wants is

```
grep '^[^#]*test' /etc/oratab
```

or

```
grep "^[^#]*$DBNAME" /etc/oratab
```

which searches for a line where `test` appears,
and all the characters before it are something other than `#`.

As usual, you should always quote your shell variable references
(e.g., `"$DB_NAME"` and `"$env_var"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
And, [as Stéphane Chazelas points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439691/80216#comment795266_439693),
if `$DBNAME` looks like a non-trivial regular expression
(e.g., it contains **`.`**, `*` or `[`…`]`),
there are likely to be unwanted results.