# Grep string only in uncommented line

Tags: shell, grep, make

How can I grep the string which is only in uncommented line? I don't want the result to be included for string in commented line. For example:
In file.tx

```
My name is Jane
#My name is Sara
```

I want to grep word "name" and print the output, like below: -

```
My name is Jane
```

But I don't want the commented line to be display to.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep for a text in a line. But if it has a comment only at its beginning then exclude it from the grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439691/grep-for-a-text-in-a-line-but-if-it-has-a-comment-only-at-its-beginning-then-ex)

Comment: @mosvy I was thinking along those lines too (but `grep '^[^#]*pattern'`, to prevent any `#` from creeping in anywhere before the pattern), may I suggest posting that as an answer?

Comment: @StephenKitt Not that easy ... your command will filter this: `echo "# pattern"` which is not a comment.

Comment: @RoVo true, the answer depends very much on the context. If the OP is trying to parse shell code, then the only reliable way to go about this is to write a shell parser ;-). I was thinking of configuration files myself.

Comment: you're right, for most use cases this will be enough, but it's not a general solution. As the question stands, it is not clear, but OP says "uncommented **line**" which indicates that your solution would fit.

Comment: @StephenKitt My first (single-regexp,`'^[^#].*pattern`) solution is broken -- it will miss lines where `pattern` should match at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the line which is not commented out in a file, then below commands comes handy.

```
grep -v '^ *#' filename.txt  | grep searchstring
```

> -v -> Inverse 
>   -v "^ *#" -> Print the lines without "#" in the starting line (# ABC - This line is also avoided)

It has worked for me for a very long time & I use this to display the active crontab jobs.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but mine doesn't work. I use this in unix

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it is not possible to give a perfect answer.
You can run something along the lines of:

```
remove the comments (and maybe literal strings)   | 
grep in the output
```

Removing comments (multiline or not) can be tricky... 
We need at least a language specific lexical analyzer to correctly deal with it.

Anyway we can write a quick hack (that is not so robust)
Following an example with C comments:

```
   perl -0pe 's!/\*.*?\*/!!gs' x.c   | grep searchstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work (assuming commented lines start with a `#` sign):

```
grep -v '^#' myfile.txt | grep string_to_search
```

You can replace `#` with any symbol that indicates a comment line (`C`, `c`, `d`, `D`, `*` or `!` e.g.)

Comment: Hi anonymous downvoter, can you explain ?

Comment: I did not downvote, but this will print just any line which does not start with `#`, but OP wants to search a pattern when line is not commented.

Comment: @Kusalananda You can replace `#` with any other character, hence my example and its explanation. And if the comments are multi-lines, `grep` will not be sufficient and you'll need a dedicated parser.

Comment: That should all be part of your answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but mine doesn't work. I use this in unix

Comment: I also use Unix. Which flavor and which shell do you use ? (BSD, Solaris / bash, ksh, etc)